# me falla la calculadora

Tags: javascript, html, css

Ahora estuve intentando crear una calculadora y tengo un error. Aquí mi archivo html:

```js
 function ini() {
    var uno =  document.getElementById("uno")
    var dos = document.getElementById("dos")
    var tres =  document.getElementById("tres")
    var cuatro =  document.getElementById("cuatro")
    var cinco =  document.getElementById("cinco")
    var seis = document.getElementById("seis")
    var siete =  document.getElementById("siete")
    var ocho = document.getElementById("ocho")
    var nueve =  document.getElementById("nueve")
    var cero = document.getElementById("cero")
    var mas =  document.getElementById("mas")
    var menos = document. getElementById("menos")
    var por =  document.getElementById("por")
    var entre =  document.getElementById("entre")
    var c =  document.getElementById("c")
    var resul = document.getElementById("resul")


    var uno.onclick =function(e){
        resul.textcontent=textcontent + "1";
    }
}
```

```css
 body{
    background: lightblue;
}
.calculadora{
    margin: 0px auto;
    padding: 53px;
    background-color: blue;
    display: block;
    width: 400px;
    height: 550px;
    border-radius: 20px;
}
.calculadora td button{
    cursor: pointer;
    display: block;
    height: 70px;
    width: 70px;
    border-radius: 7px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    font-size: 20px;
}
#resul{
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 50px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    width: 300px;
    height: 100px;
    line-height: 100px;
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: 9px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    color: #303030;
    overflow-y: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="C:\Users\USER\OneDrive\luis fernando\paginas web\css\calculadora 1.0.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="C:\Users\USER\OneDrive\luis fernando\paginas web\javaScript\calculadora 1.0.js"></script>
<body onload= ini() >
    <table class="calculadora">
        <tr>
            <td colspan="4"><span id="resul"></span></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td><button id="uno">1</button></td>
            <td><button id="dos">2</button></td>
            <td><button id="tres">3</button></td>
            <td><button id="entre">/</button></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td><button id="cuatro">4</button></td>
            <td><button id="cinco">5</button></td>
            <td><button id="seis">6</button></td>
            <td><button id="por">x</button></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td><button id="siete">7</button></td>
            <td><button id="ocho">8</button></td>
            <td><button id="nueve">9</button></td>
            <td><button id="menos">-</button></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td><button id="c">C</button></td>
            <td><button id="cero">0</button></td>
            <td><button id="igual">=</button></td>
            <td><button id="mas">+</button></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

No sé por qué falla mi código y no aparece el número 1 en la parte del resultado. El código por el momento está incompleto, pero yo quiero que al presionar 1 en la pantalla, me salga uno, algo que aún no logro hacerlo.

Comment: Si detallas mejor la pregunta e indicando el error que presentas puedes omitir los caracteres sin sentido que pusiste en la pregunta.

Comment: Se pide que escribas más texto para que te esfuerces en explicar el problema, no para que coloques texto sin sentido.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

He preparado un [ejemplo mínimo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) a partir de tu código, de manera que quitemos todo el *ruido* que produce ver tanto, para algo más sencillo.

Tu primer error está en anteponer la palabra `var` a la asignación del evento `onClick` del botón. Debido a que javascript espera la declaración de una variable, se queja de encontrar un `.` luego del primer identificador (las variables debieran ser identificadores simples).

Luego, en el código de la función utilizas la propiedad `textcontent` de `resul` para asignarle el resultado de `texcontent` (ya no de `resul`) más la cadena `1`. Si esto llegar a ejecutarse, se tendría que quejar de que `texcontent` no está declarado o usar el valor `null`.

Como sea, te recomiendo utilizar `innerText` y no olvidar calificar las dos veces el nombre, pues en ambas ocasiones queremos usar el `innerText` de `resul`, tanto para agregarle el uno, como para asignar este nuevo valor al *campo* visible para el usuario.

```js
function ini() {
    let uno =  document.getElementById("uno")
    let dos = document.getElementById("dos")
    let resul = document.getElementById("resul")

    uno.onclick = function(e) {
      resul.innerText = resul.innerText + "1";
    }
    
}
```

```css
body{
    background: lightblue;
}
.calculadora{
    margin: 0px auto;
    padding: 53px;
    background-color: blue;
    display: block;
    width: 400px;
    height: 550px;
    border-radius: 20px;
}
.calculadora td button{
    cursor: pointer;
    display: block;
    height: 70px;
    width: 70px;
    border-radius: 7px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    font-size: 20px;
}
#resul{
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 50px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    width: 300px;
    height: 100px;
    line-height: 100px;
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: 9px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    color: #303030;
    overflow-y: none;
}
```

```html
<body onload= ini() >
    <table class="calculadora">
        <tr>
            <td colspan="4"><span id="resul"></span></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><button id="uno">1</button></td>
            <td><button id="dos">2</button></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
```